# Acceleration of wheel

Tags: android, math, rotation, acceleration

I am trying to calculate the acceleration of the rotateable wheel i have implemented.

But i have a hard time figuring out how i would calculate that. So any tips that could help me out is appreciated

The wheel itself is a created on my `onDraw()` method.

**How i rotate the wheel**

```
@Override
    public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
        if (rotationEnabled) {
            switch (motionEvent.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    double currentAngle = getAngle(motionEvent.getX(), motionEvent.getY());

                    rotateMe((float) (startAngle - currentAngle));
                    startAngle = startAngle - currentAngle;
                    break;
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    break;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private double getAngle(double xTouch, double yTouch) {
        double x = xTouch - (getMeasuredWidth() / 2d);
        double y = getMeasuredHeight() - yTouch - (getMeasuredHeight() / 2d);

        switch (getQuadrant(x, y)) {
            case 1:
                return Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
            case 2:
                return 180 - Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
            case 3:
                return 180 + (-1 * Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI);
            case 4:
                return 360 + Math.asin(y / Math.hypot(x, y)) * 180 / Math.PI;
            default:
                return 0;
        }
    }

    private static int getQuadrant(double x, double y) {
        if (x >= 0) {
            return y >= 0 ? 1 : 4;
        } else {
            return y >= 0 ? 2 : 3;
        }
    }

    private void rotateMe(float degrees) {
        setRotation(degrees);
    }
```

**Update**

The goal is to setup a timer. That goes from minutes to hours. I need the acceleration to jump from minutes to hours faster. All should be depended on how fast the user drags the wheel

So after touch event (When user stops touching the wheel). There should be no velocity attached to it.

Comment: You can avoid all quadrant computations by using `angle = Math.atan2(y,x) *180/Math.Pi;`. This will give the angle in the range [-180, 180], you would have to add 360 to negative values.

Comment: Please describe further what "acceleration" is. Obviously, it is a reaction to the touch event. What would be the state before the touch, what should be the state after the touch? How should the transition look like?

Comment: I still do not understand your "acceleration". Somehow you want to measure the angular velocity `omega`. You will have to introduce time to do that, up to now your code is static relative to time. So having `omega` in degrees per second, what is the result you want to compute?